# How to continuous check if array is sorted after removes/adds/updates of elements

Tags: algorithm

Supposing that a list of n integers is given (The list don't need to be already sorted). How to check if the list is sorted (NON-INCREASING OR NON-DECREASING) after remove ,update or insert values ?

The only thing i can think to solve this problem is keeping a linked list of the numbers with the operations of remove[O(n)],insert[O(n)] and update [O(n)] and a linear check to see if its sorted NON-DECREASING OR NON-INCREASING. Is possible to solve this problem faster ?

> Remove,insert and update means that the user will give a position to remove/insert/update and the value with will be inserted, removed or added on the given position.
>
> There will be a query at any moment on the input to ask which state the list is (NON-INCREASING or NON-DECREASING)

Comment: Why not just write a helper method for adding/removing/updating methods that sorts them afterwards? IE: `function arrayAdd(list, value) { list.push(value); list.sort(); }`

Comment: Do you specifically mean a `std::list` or just a sequence of values (e.g. could be a `std::vector`)?

Comment: Can you run the check with the assumption that only 1 operation has been executed?

Comment: Remove does not distort the sort order. Add can be implemented with a binary search to insert in the correct spot to maintain sorting. Update can be implemented as remove/add.

Comment: any representation is valid. std::vector or std::list.

Comment: Do you intend to keep the container sorted (i.e. after insert/modification the container should remain sorted), or do you just want to be able to efficiently check if the container has remained sorted?

Comment: I just want to keep checking if the list is remaining sorted

Comment: There are several alternatives, depending on which operations you want to support with a low algorithmical complexity. Clarify?

Comment: "I just want to keep checking if the list is remaining sorted" - huh?? just check the previous and next element...

Comment: Successive remotions/adds/updates can be made. The program has a query input and has to answer if the list is sorted NON-INCREASING OR NON-DECREASING at each moment.

Comment: I think you are asking that "at any time the list can be in a sorted or unsorted state. Any operation on this list needs to quickly update the state according to whether it is now sorted or not sorted." so all the "keep it sorted" suggestions aren't what you want. Right?

Comment: yep. You're right... I have clarified the post after the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the logic of nondecreasing (duplicate it with a twist for nonincreasing).

Keep track of the number of adjacent pairs `x, y` such that `x > y`, i.e., *decreasing pairs*. The list is nondecreasing if and only if this number is zero.

To insert `b` between `a` and `c` (`a, c => a, b, c`):

```
num_decreasing_pairs -= a > c
num_decreasing_pairs += a > b
num_decreasing_pairs += b > c
```

To remove `b` between `a` and `c` (`a, b, c => a, c`):

```
num_decreasing_pairs -= a > b
num_decreasing_pairs -= b > c
num_decreasing_pairs += a > c
```

To update `b1` to `b2` between `a` and `c` (`a, b1, c => a, b2, c`):

```
num_decreasing_pairs -= a > b1
num_decreasing_pairs -= b1 > c
num_decreasing_pairs += a > b2
num_decreasing_pairs += b2 > c
```

All of these statements should be guarded by ifs that check that the examined elements are present (edge cases).

Answer (score 2):

If you maintain a list of linked lists of the values where each sub-linked list is in ascending order you know you have a sorted list when there is only one sub-linked-list.

Now the operations are:-

- remove - if removing from the start or end of a sublist, check if you can now join two sublists into one.
- add - if this breaks a sublist order, split the sublist into two new ones
- update - same as a remove and an add.

*[omitting lots of details about linked lists, access to head / tail, count values to get to the correct sub-linked-list quickly, ...]*

Answer (score 0):

The list should still be sorted after a `Remove` (assuming the code doesn't do anything silly) so that one's solved. For `Insert`, write the function such that it adds the new element in the correct position. Treat `Update` as a `Remove` followed by `Insert`. If you *really* wish to pursue the 'is it ordered' criteria, use a closure to determine if two list elements are or are not ordered, then just partition the list into overlapping pairs of two and map the closure over the resultant set of pairs. If the map contains no false results, indicating that all the overlapping pairs are ordered, you're golden.

When implemented in Clojure (Lisp variant) this looks like:

```
(defn is-ordered? [c f]
  "Determines if a collection is in sorted order as defined by the function f.
   c is a collection
   f is a function which accepts a collection for an argument, returning
   true if the collection is 'ordered' by  f's definition of 'ordered', and false
   if not."
  (not (contains? (set (map f (partition 2 1 c))) false)))
```

Best of luck.

Comment: As author stated - list may not be sorted initially.

Answer (score -1):

You could use automatic binary search for optimal performance.

Example:

```cs
class InternalList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private static readonly T[] Empty = new T[0];

    private int version;
    private int size;
    private T[] items;
    private IComparer<T> comparer;

    public InternalList() : this(0, null) { }
    public InternalList(int capacity) : this(capacity, null) { }

    public InternalList(int capacity, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (capacity < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("capacity");
        }

        this.items = (capacity == 0) ? Empty : new T[capacity];
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (size == items.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref items, (size == 0 ? 4 : size * 2));
        }

        int index = Search(item);

        if (index != size)
        {
            Array.Copy(items, index, items, index + 1, size - index);
        }

        items[index] = item;
        size++;
        version++;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }

        if (index != size - 1)
        {
            Array.Copy(items, index + 1, items, index, (size - index) - 1);
        }

        items[--size] = default(T);
        version++;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        if (size != 0)
        {
            Array.Clear(items, 0, size);
            size = 0;
            version++;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    private int Search(T item)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = size;

        while (true)
        {
            int d = (y - x) / 2;
            int n = comparer.Compare(items[x + d], item);

            if (n < 0)
            {
                if (d == 0)
                {
                    return x + 1;
                }

                x += d;

                continue;
            }
            else if (n > 0)
            {
                if (d == 0)
                {
                    return x;
                }

                y -= d;

                continue;
            }

            return x + d;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private InternalList<T> list;
        private int version;
        private int index;
        private T current;

        internal Enumerator(InternalList<T> list)
        {
            this.list = list;
            this.version = list.version;
            this.index = -1;
            this.current = default(T);
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }

                return current;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (version != list.version)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            if (index < list.size - 1)
            {
                current = list.items[++index];

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (version != list.version)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            index = -1;
            current = default(T);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

However, if lists are expected to be long, and if additions are expected to be illogical, then it may be wiser to use `System.Generic.SortedList`, assuming that you're using DotNET.

Concerning your request to automatically track the order of lists; that is certainly a poor design. The time consumed by all the interrupting checks could be used to sort a list from scratch.